# Can Intraweb Run More that 65,536 concurrent sessions?

Tags: delphi, file, caching, session, intraweb

Im trying to build a web-link to a busy social networking website using intraweb.

Intraweb creates temporary folders for each session to store temporary files, which auto-delete when the session expires.

If hosted on Win 32, the limit is 65,536 folders - which means only 65k concurrent sessions are possible.

Is there a way to turn off the temp file creation or allow for more concurrent sessions in intraweb?

Comment: In case you were willing to consider an alternative: Because I was looking for a way do build web-applications with Delphi, and was not content with IntraWeb, I have started this project: http://xxm.sourceforge.net/ It's built from the bottom up to do as little extra work as possible, like creating temp dirs and files. The interface with the hosting-framework gives the programmer full control over session management.

Answer (score 7):

IntraWeb is just not designed for handling such session amounts. IntraWeb is designed for Web *applications* and not for Web *sites*. Eventhough a plain IntraWeb session takes only a few kbytes, IntraWeb's session handling model is more a "fat" model. It is perfectly suited for creating complex stateful applications that can handle a few hundred concurrent sessions.

For Web sites with thousands of users per day - where many users just open one page and go away again - you /could/ certainly use Webbroker - but that basically means that you have to build up everything from scratch.

If you are a Delphi guy then I would recommend looking into Delphi Prism plus ASP.NET. There are tons of ASP.NET controls that simplify building your Web site in a rapid way.  ASP.NET controls from DevExpress.com, Telerik.com and others work perfectly fine in Delphi Prism.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you'll run out of system resources before you get close to 65,000 users on one box.  To handle that load you'll need a load-balanced cluster, and then the 65K limit won't be an issue.  I would not focus on this limitation.

Comment: One instance of IIS handles 64,000 connections, see for example http://highscalability.com/plentyoffish-architecture - they use a load balancer but this is just to swap hardware without interruption